# CD Player Makes Sound, Doesn't Play CD's

Tags: honda, crv

I have a 2004 Honda CRV EX which has a CD player. There are jammed CD's within the player itself as I hear mechanical noises within but the CD's don't play. The radio and tape deck is functional but there is a noise from the CD player every time I start the vehicle. Is there a way to stop this noise or a way to correct it?

Comment: Your best bet is to remove the deck, then dismantle to get the stuck CDs out, IMHO.

Comment: Agree with Paulster2. If the CDs won't eject and they are jammed, the player is going to probably keep trying to align, move or spin them. Only thing you can do is open it up to remove the CDs.

Comment: You say CDs, as in more than one, is this a cassette based system or some sort of multi-loader that takes all the CDs through the same slot?